# How to display a number with a space between currency and the number

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't find a way to display a number with a space between the currency and the number.
If I use the follow syntax:

```
select to_char(99.90,'FML90D99') from dual;
```

I get the following result:

```
$99.9
```

However the result I need is with a space between the dollar sign and the number

```
$ 99.9
```

How can I achieve this?
If I use the following you get an error

```
select to_char(99.90,'FML 90D99') from dual;
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this (by defining your currency):

```
SELECT to_char(800, 'FML999G990D00', 'NLS_CURRENCY=''$ ''') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to hardcode the currency in your code, you can use:

```
SQL> select to_char(0,'FML') || ' ' || to_char(99.90,'FM90D99') from dual;

TO_CHAR(0,'FML')||
------------------
$ 99,9
```

This even works if you have a different currency:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_currency = '£';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_char(0,'FML') || ' ' || to_char(99.90,'FM90D99') from dual;

TO_CHAR(0,'FML')||
------------------
£ 99,9
```